# deleting a product by id in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a WebAPI.

I would like to delete a product by the id. 
However, with my code, it deleted all the records.
When I key in the id number, instead of deleting the id itself, it deleted the whole records.
May I know what is wrong with my code?
how can I improve it to delete it by id.

productcontroller.cs

```
  function ProductViewModel(product) {
                var self = this;

                self.Id = product.Id;
                self.Name = product.Name;
                self.Price = product.Price;
                self.Category = product.Category;
            }

            self.products = ko.observableArray();   // Contains the list of products
            self.product = ko.observable();

            self.status = ko.observable();


public void DeleteProduct(int id)
{
     Product item = repository.Get(id);
     if (item == null)
     {
          throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
     }
     repository.Remove(id);    
}
```

.cshtml

```
 // Get delete product


 self.remove = function () {

    self.products.remove();
    $.getJSON("/api/products", function (products) {
        $.each(products, function (index, product) {
            self.products.pop(new ProductViewModel(product));
        })
    });
}
```

productrespository.cs

```
public void Remove(int id)
        {
            products.RemoveAll(p => p.Id == id);
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your repository.Remove() code?

Comment: Are they deleted from the db or the ui? pop removes items from the array, so `self.products.pop(new ProductViewModel(product));` doesn't make sense. Use push to add items. There also isn't call to the web api to delete a product, E.g. `$.ajax({ url: '/api/products/'+ id, type: 'DELETE' })`

Comment: Hi, I'm actually removing from array/ui, not from database.

Comment: Ok, then web api is irrelevant here. Are you using some javascript mvvm or similar framework (e.g. knockout)?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments in the question, I think you should have something like this.

```
function ProductsViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    this.products = ko.observableArray();
    this.delete = function (product) {
        // remove from the db
        $.when($.ajax({ url: '/api/products/' + product.id, type: 'DELETE'}))
         .done(function(){
            // and then from the ui
            self.products.remove(product);
        }).fail(function(){
            // couldn't remove from the db
            alert('failed to remove product');
        });
    };
}


<!-- ko foreach: products -->
  <button data-bind="event: { click: $parent.delete }" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Hi, I have my productviewmodel done up initially.
sorry about it. 
do take a look at the code, ive just edited it